# matching pattern with regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have written a pattern to match typedef followed by any number of characters until it matches the 1st opening braces followed by a * , then a word , closing braces and so on.
the pattern is

```
pattern_funp = re.compile(r"typedef(.*?)\(\*(\w+)\s*\)\s*\(.*?\)\s*")
```

The above pattern matches acpi_adr_space_setup in the line below which is correct:

```
typedef acpi_status(*acpi_adr_space_setup) (acpi_handle region_handle,u32 function,void *handler_context,  void **region_context);
```

but in the below line it matches func which is not what i want:

```
typedef void *call_rcu_func_t (struct rcu_head *head,void (*func1)(struct rcu_head *head));
```

The pattern should match the 1st ( followed by * not the 2nd (with *.

Comment: Then what you want to match in the 2nd example?

Comment: the regex should not match the 2nd example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure getting what you mean, but if you want not to match anything after the 1st parenthesis, putting `[^(]` instead of `.` should do the trick:

```
pattern_funp = re.compile(r"typedef([^(]*?)\(\*(\w+)\s*\)\s*\(.*?\)\s*")
```